# What's the purpose of Aurra Sing appearing in Star Wars Episode One?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In Star Wars Episode One, the bounty hunter [Aurra Sing](http://www.starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/characters/aurrasing/) can be seen for a few seconds watching the pod race on Tatooine. She never reappears again in this episode or any other episodes, though later she appears in the Clone Wars cartoon.

[image: Aurra Sing in Episode One]

Does anyone know **why she was in the movie**? Was there any particular reason for her (and not someone else from the Expanded Universe) appearing in the movie watching that race (other than selling some more merchandising stuff)? Or were there some other scenes that featured her but were cut out later?

Comment: I suppose it was to make her known and then put her in some small scene with Fett's son for training But as we see later it doesn't happen. Cut in the script somewhere?

Comment: @Alonzo You might be right, I don't know. Never found an answer to this on the Net, though (for some strange reason) it always interested me.

Comment: I wouldn't of thought there to be a reason, merely someone to fill in the spaces but I'm not George Lucas. Maybe it was a way to find if Aurra Sing was a worthy character and in my mind she is.

Comment: But jokes aside, I would rather wonder why there is a name and biography for her. The reason for her single appearance doesn't really need much reason, except that movies always have one-time appearance-characters/people; more than just main characters.

Comment: I think she was hired to kill the Jedi and take Anikan by Sidous from what I read. Or a spy.
If you read outlander she might have been hired Gradulla the Hutt to The Tusken leader who was a jedi named the howlrunner Hett. Those are throeys but I those are exanderd unisverse theorys with the comic.
Ps my spelling is horrible

Comment: If you check the "Star Wars Character Encyclopedia" for a closer photo of Aurra Sing, you might notice a close resemblence to Gwynneth Paltrow-Steven Spielberg's god daughter. Not sure if this is true, but I believe it.
~Ben Crowell

Comment: @paddotk That is the Star Wars way. Everything you see in the movies (and books and comic books) has a name and a biography. Every plant, every animal, every sentient being, every planet... everything. It's a bit different approach to world-building than the standard in movie-land.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As far as I know, there were no intended extra scenes for Aurra Sing. She was based on a sketch by the concept artist Doug Chiang who was designing female bounty hunters at the time, and was popular enough with GL to get one of his 'stamps' on the artwork and a live appearance. She turned out to be enigmatic enough to become a fan favorite, and prompted a slew of back story which also resulted in her appearance in the new Clone Wars series.

So many of these 'blink and you miss 'em' characters appear in the Star Wars saga - often elevated to more prominence due to fan demand (look at Hammerhead in the cantina, or Bossk from Vader's bounty hunter team). For me, it's part of the appeal of the saga - a glimpse at a much larger galaxy.